# Package geomorph not reading negative values

Tags: r, na, missing-data

When using the package geomorph to read the .TPS data on this link (https://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.c5j1bb6c) it appears to omit the negative values. So, following downloading the zip file for .TPS data:

```
install.packages("geomorph")
library(geomorph)
LM1 <- readland.tps("LM1.TPS", specID = "ID")
```

and then when you View() the data, it's converted any negative values to NAs. Does anyone know why this would be?

Thanks.

Comment: Me too, filed an issue: https://github.com/geomorphR/geomorph/issues/15